# How to toggle dynamically generated dropdowns using the .map functions index?

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I have a array that for every item in the array a drop down list is dynamically generated. Right now each drop down list share the same toggle boolean so they all open and close and the same time, how can I make this work individually?

I map each object to a index here and then start creating dropdowns:

```
{Object.keys(props.totalWorkload.options).map((item, i) => (
        <WorkloadOptions
          key={i}
          cnt={i}
          appendChoiceList={props.appendChoiceList}
          modalDropDown={props.modalDropDown}
          toggleDropDown={props.toggleDropDown}
          totalWorkloadOptions={props.totalWorkload.options[item]}
        />
      ))}
```

When the Drop Down options component is created I pass the index to a function:

```
<div>
    <Dropdown isOpen={props.modalDropDown} toggle={props.toggleDropDown.bind(props.cnt)}>
      <DropdownToggle caret>{props.totalWorkloadOptions.optionTitle}</DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        {props.totalWorkloadOptions.options.map(op => (
          // tslint:disable-next-line:no-invalid-this
          // tslint:disable-next-line:jsx-no-lambda
          <DropdownItem key={op} onClick= {() => props.appendChoiceList(props.totalWorkloadOptions.optionTitle, op)}>
            {op}
          </DropdownItem>
        ))}
      </DropdownMenu>
      <strong> {props.totalWorkloadOptions.optionDescription} </strong>
    </Dropdown>
    <br />
  </div>
```

The it will arrrive at the following functuion and console log the index and then set the appropriate toggle value in an array to true/false:

```
  toggleDropDown = (index: any) => {
    console.log('triggered!:' + index);
    let clicked = this.state.modalDropDownClicked;
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-conditional-assignment
    if (clicked[index]=!clicked[index]){
      this.setState({ modalDropDownClicked: !this.state.modalDropDown[index] });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the following pattern to toggle dynamically created elements:

```js
// Item.js

class Item extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    const { id, onClick } = this.props;
    onClick(id);
  }
  
  render() {
    const { isOpen } = this.props;
    
    return (
    <li><button onClick={this.handleClick}>{isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'}</button></li>
    )
  }
}


// App.js

class App extends React.Component {
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    const { items } = nextProps;
    if (items !== prevState.prevPropsItems) {
      return { items, prevPropsItems: items };
    }
    return null;
  }
  
  state = {
    prevPropsItems: [],
    items: []
  }
  
  toggleItem = id => this.setState(prevState => {
    const items = prevState.items.map(item => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        return { ...item, isOpen: !item.isOpen }
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    });
    return { items }
  })
  
  render(){
    const { items } = this.state;
    
    return (<ul>
      {items.map(item => <Item key={item.id} id={item.id} onClick={this.toggleItem} isOpen={item.isOpen} />)}
    </ul>);
  }
}

// AppContainer.js

const itemsFromRedux = [
      { id: '1', isOpen: false },
      { id: '2', isOpen: false },
      { id: '3', isOpen: false },      
    ]

ReactDOM.render(<App items={itemsFromRedux} />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you this is a big help ill try implement it, the array wont be fixed since it will come from a GET but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: In this case the items should be a prop of App (assuming you are using e.g. redux). And use getDerivedStateFromProps to convert the props to state whenever they refreshing, so you can handle their open state inside the App component.

Comment: This is the first time I've heard of GetDerivedStateFromProps , is it necessary when implemeting these dynamically generated dropdowns? The flow of my code here is use MapStateToProps to receive a object with an array of objects inside, this inner array of objects gets iterated over to create the dropdowns, for each drop-down a nth Boolean should be created to control the nth drop-down, the inner objects pass a cnt prop taken from the .map index, this in the passed to the component that represents the drop-down which should used this as a index number to pass to my toggle function

Comment: Right now that index from the map function logs as Object object, I want to be able to compare this to and array of booleans and implemet this in the way you have above

Comment: The `open` and `close` are a states of the App, so nicer to use state for it as it is designed for it. It is no reason to avoid the normal pattern using additional booleans etc.. (if I understood well). If you'd like to I complete my code with the getDerivedStateFromProps part, it is not complicated at all.

Comment: Could you please add it and when I'm able to code later I will try implemet it in my code following your pattern?

Comment: I added the getDerivedStateFromProps part. However in my implementation if the items is being refresed in redux, all boolean go back to false. But you can fine-tune the getDer... function to handle it, to keep the open ones open.

Comment: Currently trying to just get the toggle working then implementing getDerivedStateFromProps, I'll have to refactor my code which could be difficult since im using Typescript but ill update here if I can get it working.