# Best way to reorder a list realtime in React-Redux?

Tags: javascript, sorting, react-redux

I'm currently build an app that have a realtime list. the view of list as bellow picture:
[image]

This list will be updated realtime, when one of these actions is trigger:

- A message is updated, the updated_time will be changed
- Receive new message
- Receive unread status of message

So I want to sort this list base on two conditions:

1. All unRead_message allways at the top
2. All message should be sorted by updated_time DESC (newest first), except unread_message always in prioty.

The data of this list is controled by these reduceres:

```
    export const data = createReducer(
    {},
    {
        [ CONVERSATIONS_RECEIVE ]: ( state, { conversations } ) => {
            return reduce(
                conversations,
                ( memo, conversation ) => {
                    const { id } = conversation.data;

                    if ( memo === state ) {
                        memo = { ...memo };
                    }

                    memo[ id ] = conversation;
                    return memo;
                },
                state
            );
        },
        [ RECEIVED_PENDING_MESSAGE ]: ( state, { data } ) => {

            if ( !data || !data.conversation_id in state ) return state;

            return update( state, {
                [ data.conversation_id ]: { data: { $merge: { snippet: data.message, updated_time: data.created_time } } }
            } )
        },
        [ RECEIVED_CONVERSATION_SEEN ]: ( state, { data } ) => {
            if ( !data || !data.conversation_id in state ) return state;

            return update( state, {
                [ data.conversation_id ]: { data: { $merge: { seen: true } } }
            } )
        },
        [ RECEIVED_CONVERSATION_UNSEEN ]: ( state, { data } ) => {
            if ( !data || !data.conversation || !data.conversation.id in state ) return state;

            return update( state, {
                [ data.conversation.id ]: { data: { $merge: { seen: false } } }
            } )
        },
    }
);

export function keys( state = [], action ) {
    switch ( action.type ) {
        case CONVERSATIONS_RECEIVE:
            if ( !action.conversations || !action.conversations.length ) return state;
            return state.concat( action.conversations.map( conversation => conversation.data.id ) );
        default:
    }

    return state;
}

export default combineReducers( {
    keys,
    data,
    isRequesting,
} );
```

The list data rendered by an array of keys:

```
[
  "id_1",
  "id_2",
  //....
]
```

and the data:

```
[
    {
        "data": {
            "can_comment": false,
            "can_hide": false,
            "can_like": false,
            "can_reply": true,
            "can_reply_privately": false,
            "comment_id": "",
            "id": "hbiocjgwxpncbnja8a3rra4oke",
            "is_hidden": false,
            "is_private": false,
            "last_seen_by": "ckj7mny56jrmir4df8h466uk7a",
            "message": "",
            "page_id": "1651651651651651",
            "post_id": "",
            "private_reply_conversation": "null",
            "scoped_thread_key": "t_1221211454699392",
            "seen": true,
            "snippet": " [ TRI ÂN VÀNG-NGÀN ƯU ĐÃI ] \nMiễn phí ship tận nhà \nChỉ còn 350k trọn bộ COMBO 3 sản phẩm tuyệt vời cho chị em và các bé nhà mình : \n Vòng tay chỉ đỏ kim vàng đính đá topaz được nhập từ Thái Lan \n Dây chuyền hồ ly hợp mệnh \n Vòng tay dâu tằm cho bé \nKhuyến mại chỉ áp dụng với những khách hàng đáng yêu nhận được tin nhắn này.Nhanh tay để lại SỐ ĐIỆN THOẠI để được thỉnh bộ sản phẩm với giá siêu khuyến mại này Chị  Chị Hai nha ",
            "type": "message",
            "unread_count": 0,
            "updated_time": "2018-12-07T12:00:21+0000"
        },
        "tags": [],
        "from": {
            "id": "1223645637789307",
            "name": "Chị Hai"
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "can_comment": false,
            "can_hide": false,
            "can_like": false,
            "can_reply": true,
            "can_reply_privately": false,
            "comment_id": "",
            "id": "7oemjmkpxidi7cgk99ggbdamdw",
            "is_hidden": false,
            "is_private": false,
            "last_seen_by": "ckj7mny56jrmir4df8h466uk7a",
            "message": "",
            "page_id": "1651651651651651",
            "post_id": "",
            "private_reply_conversation": "null",
            "scoped_thread_key": "t_279998559200944",
            "seen": true,
            "snippet": "Giá hơi cao",
            "type": "message",
            "unread_count": 0,
            "updated_time": "2018-12-07T12:00:19+0000"
        },
        "tags": [],
        "from": {
            "id": "280004999200300",
            "name": "Chung Ngoc"
        }
    },
    // ..... other items
]
```

I have tried:

```
function mysortfunction(a, b) {

    // always sort by updated_time first
    if ( a.data.updated_time > b.data.updated_time ) return 1;
    if ( a.data.updated_time <= b.data.updated_time ) return -1;

    // if BOTH a.seen == false AND b.seen == false, we'll sort a & b by updated_time
    if ( !a.data.seen && !b.data.seen ) {
        if ( a.data.updated_time > b.data.updated_time ) return 1;
        if ( a.data.updated_time <= b.data.updated_time ) return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me the best way to sort this list base on my conditions above, Thanks you very much!

Comment: did you try anything to sort them?

Comment: Please, have a look on my other answer. This provides a pattern how to handle dynamic children from store. It may give you useful inputs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189290/how-to-toggle-dynamically-generated-dropdowns-using-the-map-functions-index/53190175#53190175

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı: sorry, I've edited my question to show what I have tried!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort on multiple values in the following way:

```js
const data = [
  { seen: true, updated_time: 'A' },
  { seen: true, updated_time: 'A' },
  { seen: false, updated_time: 'A' },
  { seen: false, updated_time: 'A' },
  { seen: false, updated_time: 'B' },
];
//compare booleans, returns -1,0 or 1
const compareSeen = (direction) => (a, b) =>
  a.seen === b.seen
    ? 0
    : a.seen
      ? -1 * direction
      : 1 * direction;
//compare strings, returns -1, 0 or 1
const compareDate = (direction) => (a, b) =>
  a.updated_time.localeCompare(b);

//pass array of compare functions and return a function that takes
//  a and b and keeps using compare functions until one of them returns non zero
const createSort = (comparers = []) => (a, b) =>
  comparers.reduce(
    (result, compareFn) =>
      result === 0 ? compareFn(a, b) : result,
    0,
  );
console.log(
  data
    .slice() //sort will mutate, we don't want that so we make a copy first
    .sort(createSort([compareSeen(-1), compareDate(1)])),
);
```

If you have ISO times from different timeZones you can not use string compare but have to map the date strings to numbers first and then map it back:

```js
const data = [
  { seen: true, updated_time: '2018-12-07T12:00:21+0000' },
  { seen: true, updated_time: '2018-12-07T12:00:21+0000' },
  { seen: false, updated_time: '2018-12-07T12:00:21+0000' },
  { seen: false, updated_time: '2018-12-07T12:00:21+0000' },
  { seen: false, updated_time: '2018-12-07T12:00:21+0100' },
];
//compare booleans, returns -1,0 or 1
const compareSeen = (direction) => (a, b) =>
  a.seen === b.seen
    ? 0
    : a.seen
      ? -1 * direction
      : 1 * direction;
//compare numbers, returns negative number, 0 or positive number
const compareDate = (direction) => (a, b) =>
  (a.updated_time - b.updated_time) * direction;

//pass array of compare functions and return a function that takes
//  a and b and keeps using compare functions until one of them returns non zero
const createSort = (comparers = []) => (a, b) =>
  comparers.reduce(
    (result, compareFn) =>
      result === 0 ? compareFn(a, b) : result,
    0,
  );
console.log(
  data
    .map((item) => ({
      ...item,
      updated_time: new Date(item.updated_time).getTime(),
    })) //map already copied data so sort will not mutate it
    .sort(createSort([compareSeen(-1), compareDate(-1)]))
    .map((item) => ({
      ...item,
      updated_time: new Date(
        item.updated_time,
      ).toISOString(),//note: now you have strings in UTC/Zulu time
    })),
);
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! Your answer is nearly fix my case, except for those items are not seen (seen = true), this snippet does not sort all item if they are seen (seen = true)

Comment: @Enesy are you sure the `seen` property is always true or false and not undefined, null, '' or 0? the `createSort([compareSeen(-1), compareDate(-1)])` means it'll sort items that have `seen` to false fist (if you use `compareSeen(1)` the true will come first). If both seen items are the same then it'll sort by highest date first (compareDate(1) will put lowest date first).

Answer (score 2):

I didn't read clearly all you code, but you can reorder your list only with javascript functions, you will use the sort() method to sort all your list by updated_time and seen or not_seen, you have to put a function to sort methode, but the only problem is that , the function passed to do the comparison need an int value as result, see their [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/sort).
so to do the trick, when doing the comparison, if his message is not seaan add to  UPDATED_TIME +1000000000 for exemple.And like that all the unseen msg will be first, and all your message sort in with one function

Comment: A couple of comments; 1. This is redux reducer so you don't want to mutate, before you can use the mutating function `sort` you have to make a copy, for example: `arr.slice().sort(...` 2. The dates are ISO date strings so you can use string compare: `a.localeCompare(b)`. 3. If you want to sort on multiple columns then you can use an array of compare functions and have the earlier functions have higher priority (only run later function if current function returns 0). For full code please see my answer.

Comment: euh, speaking for mutatung  we can also use the spread operator, I wansn't speaking about whait he is using, or if its redux or not, I just wonne to suggest him a way to sort that's all. And when I answred, he has not put the data format, so I just assumed that it was a timestamp, and if it was a timestamp, I gave him the more simple et lazy thing to do de comparison whithout hacing to use an array of compare function. Thank you for you comment

Comment: The problem I have with the `UPDATED_TIME +1000000000` solution to sort by unseen and then by update time is that your sort function is doing to much, functions should implement one thing only and if a function does more than that it should call other functions that implement that or you'll end up with functions that cannot be reused and combined with names like `sortByUnseenAndThenByDate`. If you see functions with such names that implement things instead of calling other functions then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: No, you hadn't understand the function, I will not sort by unseen then update,I will sort one and only one time, because when adding +1000000000 to  UPDATED_TIME to the unseen items, when you do the sort, you will automatically have the unssen message on top, and the others in the bottom, and of course, all the items sorted.
Thank you anyway for your recommandations