# How to make dynamic checkbox and post the data using fetch post?

Tags: reactjs, post, checkbox, event-handling, fetch

I have a constant file with this data in it:

```
export let testing= [
  { id: 'test1', label: 'Test1' },
  { id: 'test2', label: 'Test2' },
  { id: 'test3', label: 'Test3' }
]
```

In my checkboxes.js,

```
class CheckBoxes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = ({
      checkBoxArray: [],
      isChecked: false 
    })
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();     //use for testing only
   fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/testing`, {
      method: "POST",
     headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        check_box_data: event.target.check_box_name[].value,   //error
      })
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log('Success')
        } else {
          alert('Failed')
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert('Server error')
      });
  }

  handleCheckBoxChange = (index) => {     //not working
    const {checkBoxArray} = this.state;

    checkBoxArray[index].checked = !checkBoxArray[index].checked;
    this.setState({           //this line causes maximum depth mount error
      checkBoxArray
  });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
           <div>
                {
                  this.state.checkBoxArray.map((object, index) => {
                    return (
                      <CheckBoxComponent
                        key={index}
                        check_box_id={object.id}
                        check_box_name='check_box_name[]'
                        check_box_label={object.label}
                        check_box_value={object.id}
                        isChecked={this.state.isChecked}
                        handleCheckBoxChange={this.handleCheckBoxChange(index)}
                      />
                    );
                  })
                }

            <SingleButtonComponent button_type='submit' button_value='Create Now' />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default CheckBoxes;
```

In my checkbox component js:

```
import React from 'react';

const CheckBoxComponent = (props) => {
  const { check_box_id, check_box_name, check_box_label, check_box_value, isChecked, handleCheckBoxChange } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <input type='checkbox' id={check_box_id} name={check_box_name} value={check_box_value} checked={isChecked} onChange={handleCheckBoxChange}/>
      <label htmlFor={check_box_id} className='lh-copy'>&nbsp;{check_box_label}</label>
    </div>
  )
}
export default CheckBoxComponent;
```

My first problem is I can't post the checkbox value as an array in the fetch api. Apparently `[]` is not allowed in `event.target.check_box_name[].value`. I tried doing `event.target.check_box_name.value` but it returns cannot read property 'value' of undefined. I want to send an array of the checkbox values back to server.

My second problem is I do not know how to setup dynamically generated checkbox.  This piece of code will check all the check boxes. I am showing just 3 lines of data in the constant file and it is more than that so I will not accept any solution that works statically.

Comment: For dynamic checkbox implementation (without the async part) please have a look on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189290/how-to-toggle-dynamically-generated-dropdowns-using-the-map-functions-index/53190175#53190175

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not directly call function in render handleCheckBoxChange() use => or bind for that:

```
class CheckBoxes extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = ({
        checkBoxArray: [  { id: 'test1', label: 'Test1' },
        { id: 'test2', label: 'Test2' },
        { id: 'test3', label: 'Test3' }],
        isChecked: false 
      })
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();     //use for testing only
     fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/testing`, {
        method: "POST",
       headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          check_box_data: event.target.check_box_name.value,   //error
        })
      })
    }

    handleCheckBoxChange = (id) => {
      const checkBoxArray = [...this.state.checkBoxArray];
      const index = checkBoxArray.findIndex(object => object.id === id);
      checkBoxArray[index].isChecked = !checkBoxArray[index].isChecked;
      this.setState({
        checkBoxArray
      });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
             <div>
                  {
                    this.state.checkBoxArray.map((object, index) => {
                      return (
                        <CheckBoxComponent
                          key={object.id}
                          check_box_id={object.id}
                          check_box_name='check_box_name'
                          check_box_label={object.label}
                          check_box_value={object.id}
                          isChecked={object.isChecked}
                          handleCheckBoxChange={this.handleCheckBoxChange} //you can pass id here but affect performance
                        />
                      );
                    })
                  }

            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

      )
    }
  }



const CheckBoxComponent = (props) => {
  const { check_box_id, check_box_name, check_box_label, check_box_value, isChecked, handleCheckBoxChange } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <input type='checkbox' id={check_box_id} name={check_box_name} value={check_box_value} checked={isChecked} onChange={() => {handleCheckBoxChange(check_box_id)}}/>
      <label htmlFor={check_box_id} className='lh-copy'>&nbsp;{check_box_label}</label>
    </div>
  )
}

CheckBoxComponent.defaultProps = {
  isChecked: false,
}

export default CheckBoxComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks man, your solution helped me solved the checking all the boxes at once issue. To handle the multiple checkbox, don't we need to use an array for the name of checkbox like how I pass the name `check_box_name='check_box_name[]` to the checkbox component?

Comment: Also when I remove everything in the handleSubmit function and post the form, it actually worked by looking at the url. I don't know how to do the `JSON.stringify({})` though. How do I return an array of the checkbox value back to the server?

Comment: this.state.checkBoxArray will have all state of each checkbox only iterate this array and return to the server as per requirment.

Answer (score 0):

Сhecked param checkbox depends on the props isСhecked which you recorded as this.state.isChecked and never change it.

Why??

Same for each checkbox???

Change the checked conditions to

```js
<CheckBoxComponent
   key={index}
   // ... some props
   isChecked={object.checked} // you update this field in handleCheckBoxChange
/>
```